# Fetch User detail with his role in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

My Application have below setup

Users table:
id
roleid
firstname
email
password

Roles table:
id
userid
rolename

There will be total 4 fixed roles and those will be assigned to users.

Now i want related role name when i do login with user.So in laravel eloquent model how can i define the relationships and how can i fetch and display?

I am new to laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

If your relation between user and roles is **One To Many**

Have a read on below link. You'll get the idea.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many